# Jboss 4.0.5 attributes

Tags: tomcat, jboss-4.0.x

Is there **useHttpOnly** attribute  for **jboss 4.0.5**? And if there is how do i set it?
Somthing like:
    `useHttpOnly=true` in context.xml for Tomcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS), JBoss AS 4.0.5 includes Tomcat 5.5.20, so you should be able to use standard Tomcat 5.5 context.xml descriptors, including `useHttpOnly`.

Also, consider upgrading JBoss to something newer - 4.0.x is extremely old.